# How to get an executable's attributes C

Tags: android, c, apk, android-kernel, android-security

I am writing a short C program, which runs in Android environment. I like to know if there is an object I can reference which would have a pointer to the same executable. I think it would be kind of like "this" pointer in Java. My goal is to get information about he executable itself. Ideally I like to have the start address and offset of the executable in memory. 
I like to know the answer for a native C code as well as an apk which I would potentially develop later. If you know the function I need to use, please let me know. 
I have complete control over the build and target environment. That is I can get root access on the target. I can also put the app on the image to be flashed on the phone vs. pushing it via IDE to /data partition.

I guess in C, I can use the current pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/proc/<pid>`

This is the best you can get without hacking into the kernel